# Вопрос о запятой в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, как

> Есть идеи, но не знаешь(,) как их реализовать?

Нужно ли ставить запятую перед "как"? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста,  почему Вы думаете, что запятую перед третьим предложение можно не ставить?

Answer (score 3):

**(1) Есть идеи, но (2) не знаешь, (3) как их реализовать.**

Сложное предложение с сочинительной и подчинительной связью трех предикативных основ. Запятая ставится перед придаточным изъяснительным предложением, КАК ― союзное слово.

Предложение 2 ― односоставное **(обобщенно-личное),** подлежащее отсутствует.

Comment: А почему неопределенно-личное? _(Ты) не знаешь..._ Разве это не определенно-личное?

Comment: Здесь нет обращения ко второму лицу, только использована форма второго лица. Такие предложения выражают общие суждения, применимые к любому лицу.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.

Comment: *Здесь нет обращения ко второму лицу, только использована форма второго лица. Такие предложения выражают общие суждения, применимые к любому лицу.* — поэтому такие предложения называют **обобщённо**-личными.

Comment: @grizzly _Есть идеи, но (человек в целом) не знает, как их реализовать._ В таком смысле это предложение считается обобщенно-личным?

Comment: Посмотрите материал об обобщенно-личных предложениях http://yanko.lib.ru/books/language/ru/yanko.valgina_2003_416p_rasp_sl.htm#_Toc331393963

Comment: @СтепанПопов Ну, так же нельзя сказать, не имея в виду определённую личность. Посмотрите [здесь](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-023.htm) — на одной странице все три типа предложений очень хорошо описаны.

Comment: Ксения, у Вас ведь ссылка на ту же книгу. Посмотрите, это никак не может быть неопределённо-личное. Однозначно, обобщённо-личное.

Comment: Небольшая неточность, извините.  Общие суждения, конечно, используются в обобщенно-личных предложениях. В ответ внесено изменение.

Comment: А контекст влияет на тип односоставного предложения? Прочитав отрывок по ссылке, я, кажется, уловил суть. Но, к примеру: _Есть идеи, но не знаешь, как их реализовать? Тогда регистрируйся на бла-бла, мы поможем..._ или _Василий, в чем твоя проблема? Есть идеи, но не знаешь, как их реализовать? Может, тебе нужна помощь?_ Здесь также это предложение является обобщенно-личным?

Comment: Контекст влияет. В данном случае  уважаемый блогер, вероятно, поучает свою аудиторию, но при этом  обращается  к своему читателю на ты, как бы к нему одному. Здесь определенно-личное предложение.

Comment: В моём случае идет обращение не к определенному человеку. Вы правы. Это реклама.

Comment: Посмотрел по сылке, любезно указанной @grizzly, что пишет Валгина об обобщенно-личных предложениях, — и нашел подтверждение своим сомнениям. "Семантической особенностью глагольных форм в данных предложениях является обозначение вневременности." (Валгина). Вот этого-то и нет у нас. (Ср: *Любишь кататься - люби и саночки возить* — это правило на все времена). А у нас реклама, обращение к каждому, попавшему в определенную ситуцию, с призывом позвонить и т. п. По-моему, вполне определенно-личное (Не гляди же с тоской на дорогу...)

Comment: Реклама всегда обращена лично к тому, кто ее читает (это обычный рекламный стиль). Таким образом,  это обращение ко второму лицу, предложение определенно-личное.

Comment: А почему же в ответе не исправили?

Comment: Потому что не было контекста.  Такое предложение может быть обращено к любому лицу, в том числе к себе (что-то вроде размышлений). На этот вариант дан ответ. С другой стороны, это может быть обращение блогера к подписчикам или реклама (в этом случае обращаются к конкретному лицу). (Но это же не основная тема вопроса, а попутное обсуждение статуса односоставных предложений).

Answer (score 2):

**Есть идеи, но не знаешь, как их реализовать?**

Запятая ставится. Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным (дополнительным): *не знаешь* [что именно?], *как их реализовать*. Такие придаточные отвечают на вопросы косвенных падежей (что? о чем? чего? и т. д.).

[Примеры](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/738-222_pridatochnye_vremeni.html):

> Началось с того **[с чего?]**, что Колька из озорства отнял у меня книжку
>   (Гайдар).
>
> У Слободкина возникло ощущение **[чего?]**, будто он застыл в
>   беспредельном пространстве (Тельпугов).
>
> Мы наперебой расспрашивали кучеров **[о чём?]**, смирные ли у них лошади
>   (Маршак).
>
> – Юлия Дмитриевна, начальник велел **[что?]**, чтобы вы никуда не уходили
>   (Панова).
>
> Сейчас уже никто не знает **[чего?]**, откуда в курских садах пошла
>   «соловьиная школа» (Песков).

Comment: Спасибо больше за помощь! А то мы с другом спорили, я оказалась права. :)